# How to find out the html code for a currency?

Tags: html

The html code for USD '$' is `&#36;`. How could I find the html codes for other currencies? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up their hexadecimal representation in a character map (`charmap` both on Windows and in Gnome)

Then `&#codepoint;` should do the trick, e.g. `&#31;` for the digit `1`.

Comment: 'there' should be 'their'.

Answer (score 3):

here are some:

**Test for Unicode support in Web browsers Currency Symbols**

http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/currency_symbols.html

**HTML - Special Entity Codes**

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/codehtml.html

**Currency Internationalization (i18n), Multiple Currencies and Foreign Exchange (FX)**

http://www.xencraft.com/resources/multi-currency.html

**Special ASCII HTML Character Codes**

http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/index.php

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful: http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cur.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat?fbclid=IwAR1Gx-EUUSEugrYE0QPCz--YS3chVLIkM6_TaQUYfUhNLcv8O-h37aTO3-8)** native api. **[See also](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/2778#issuecomment-291697586)**

```
new Intl.NumberFormat([locales[, options]]);
```

```js
function testCurrencyDisplay(locale, currency, display) {
  let formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currencyDisplay: display,
    currency: currency
  }).format(65421.45);
  return formatted;
}

function testAndPrint(locale, currency, display) {
  console.log(`${locale} ${currency} ${display}: \t` + testCurrencyDisplay(locale, currency, display));
}

let locales = ['en-US', 'en-CA', 'es-MX', 'zh-CN', 'zh-HK', 'ja-JP', 'de-DE'];
let currencies = ['USD', 'CAD', 'MXN', 'CNY', 'HKD', 'JPY', 'EUR'];

locales.forEach((locale) => {
  currencies.forEach((currency) => {
    testAndPrint(locale, currency, 'symbol');
    testAndPrint(locale, currency, 'code');
  });
});
```